# window resize - where to listen for it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a resize throttle listener:

```
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
}, 300));
```

Would it be best (in terms of performace) to either do:

a) Place this in my main class, and inside trigger events. Inside any classes that need to do something on resize I would listen for the event and react.

Main Class:

```
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){       
    $(document).trigger("my-resize-event");
}, 300));
```

In my other classes that need to respond when window is resized:

```
$(document).on("my-resize-event", function(e){

        //do stuff
});
```

Or, b) In each of my classes that need to do something on window resize, place the resize throttler, this would repeat this code across many classes:

```
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
    //do stuff
}, 300));
```

Please note this is not an opinion based question, I want to know what would be best in terms of performance.

Comment: You should rephrase your question, it can be interpreted as an opinion based question.. which isn't allowed on SO.

Comment: Thanks I have rephrased to ask about performance

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary to do this?  The only reason I ask is that:
a) Resize events that change the look of the page tend to look a little clunky on screen, and
b) You can often accomplish what you're trying to do using CSS classes if it's just the format you're attempting to change.  CSS3 adds so many more capabilities and most of the modern browsers support a good deal of those.

Anyway, to answer your main question, the easiest way would be to have other child classes subscribe to the events so that it can cascade down to any listeners.
To do it the opposite way around will mean you'll need more complex references being passed around at the point you declare the resize event, and you may also run into race conditions where classes aren't loaded before your event listener initialises.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how separated your code blocks are, do you reuse your code a lot, i would say each block has it's own resize event handler, if you do not reuse our code in this project I would have one resize handler and distribute a custom resize message. this way you can adjust your code more easily without having to change the same code n x amount of files.

Comment: There may be a performance difference between the two methods, but it's so small that i would not worry about that.